# Reload a javascript after jetpack infnity scroll load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, jetpack

i hav a javascript  for autoplay a youtube a javascript  ist in file1.js and Jetpack infninity scroll file2.js    the file 1 work only in the posts thej ar not from infinity scroll  and at the posts thej ar loaded from jetpack infinity scroll don't work i tray a lot of posibilitys i tray to  load the javascript with infnity scroll agen to the header but thets dont work to replace the js  at the header thets wont work i don't know what can i do more. i nead a stacoverflow people help  i am sory my english is not so good and i am new in javascript world

FILE1

```
window.onload = function ani2() {
  var LoadVideo = function (player_id) {

    var Program = {

      Init: function () {
        this.NewPlayer();
        this.EventHandler();
      },

      NewPlayer: function () {
        var _this = this;
        this.Player = new YT.Player(player_id, {
          events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
          }


        });
        _this.Player.$element = $('#' + player_id);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

FILE 2

thets the file from wher play the jetpack infinity scroll

```
if (type == 'click') {

  if (response.lastbatch) {

    if (self.click_handle) {

      $('#infinite-handle').remove();
      // Update body classes
      self.body.addClass('infinity-end').removeClass('infinity-success');

    } else {
      self.body.trigger('infinite-scroll-posts-end');

    }
  } else {

    if (self.click_handle) {
      self.element.append(self.handle);
    } else {

      self.body.trigger('infinite-scroll-posts-more');
    }
  }
} else if (response.lastbatch) {

  self.disabled = true;
  self.body.addClass('infinity-end').removeClass('infinity-success');
}
```

Comment: We just can't understand your problem. Maybe you can use an another helping plateform in your language

Comment: the problem is the javascript from file1 don'T work at all posts thej are loaded from jetpack infinity scroll

Comment: Use another scroll plugin so

Comment: i tray a lot WP infnity scroll  and YITH Infinity scroll but at another plugins ar the same problem

Comment: Try to deactivate ALL your plugins first, install a standard wordpress template, and active one of your plugin infinite scroll.

Comment: i delete all the wordpress bicos it was a new wordpress and reinstall simple teme and jetpack infinity scroll and this javascript the problem is the infinity scrolldont run the javascript from fil1.js  at the new loaded post thets the problem